# Storing file on Android for Native reading

Tags: android, java-native-interface, caffe

I'm writing app for android and I'm using caffe library. My problem is that on start I need to initialize caffe, which is done by passing two files (structures of network) to caffe.
Problem is that I don't know how to store extra files on device. I've added model file to assets, but I don't know how can I read it using file path. Can you tell me where to store these file that could be access using file path?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assets are packaged and access only using special methods, so i solved problem by access file and then copy it to new location which i passed to native method.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. Just copy those files to data directory from asset folder. If you already have those files there just load them.

```
String toPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName();  // Your application path




private static boolean copyAssetFolder(AssetManager assetManager,
            String fromAssetPath, String toPath) {
        try {
            String[] files = assetManager.list(fromAssetPath);
            new File(toPath).mkdirs();
            boolean res = true;
            for (String file : files)
                if (file.contains("."))
                    res &= copyAsset(assetManager, 
                            fromAssetPath + "/" + file,
                            toPath + "/" + file);
                else 
                    res &= copyAssetFolder(assetManager, 
                            fromAssetPath + "/" + file,
                            toPath + "/" + file);
            return res;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

private static boolean copyAsset(AssetManager assetManager,
        String fromAssetPath, String toPath) {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
      in = assetManager.open(fromAssetPath);
      new File(toPath).createNewFile();
      out = new FileOutputStream(toPath);
      copyFile(in, out);
      in.close();
      in = null;
      out.flush();
      out.close();
      out = null;
      return true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private static void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them into your project as assets, and then when the app starts, you can read them from the assets and copy them into the app's private storage area. You can find this directory using [`Context.getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()).

From there, you'll be able to pass the files to Caffe.